# How to shrink or force equal height between components in row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm new to RN, I have trouble dealing with the height priority involve image which I can't seems to find a way to resolve.

Basically I want to have the Image's height to be always equal to the total height of the next view in the row (the view with `styles.itemDetails`).

The Image always grow to its image native height, and if I use `aspectRatio` it ignore the `resizeMode` property and won't grow to the available space.

[image]

Component:

```
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image style={styles.itemImg} source={source} />
      <View style={styles.itemDetails}>
        <Text>{poi.name}</Text>
        <Text>{poi.conciseDescription}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    marginTop: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  itemImg: {
    flex: 1,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 8,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  itemDetails: {
    flex: 2,
    margin: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  itemTitle: {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
});
```

Comment: you have to set the display to `flex` on the container `item:{display:flex}`.

Comment: @alan_jouhar Thanks, but adding the `display:flex` seems to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get itemDetails height with onLayout event and set to image height

```
const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(0)

<View style={styles.item}>
  <Image style={[styles.itemImg, {height: imageHeight}]} source={source} />
  <View 
       style={styles.itemDetails} 
       onLayout={e => { setImageHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height) }}
  >
    <Text>{poi.name}</Text>
    <Text>{poi.conciseDescription}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems almost does it, but for some reason it still leaving a bit of the blank space below the image, not really sure why, I'll continue to check it

Comment: I found out the height is without the `margin` value, combine it with the height from `onLayout ` works great. Unsure if there's another way to do this without having to use the callback but this would do it for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your itemImg to 1em:

```css
img {height: 1em;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_128.png" /> Your Text
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, you could try setting the parent element "item" to `inline-flex` and/ or remove `flex: 1,`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have the `em` unit in React Native sadly, removing `flex:1` cause the image to take up the whole width of the container (which I think is `flex:0`)